# Is it deliberate that the styling is broken on this site?

Tags: bug

My styling on this particular SE site is pretty bugged, is this a deliberate QA joke or an actual bug?

Surely this has been asked (if its not a bug) but I couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: Browser information?

Comment: @corsiKa latest chrome(40.0.2214.111 m), have tried with adblock on and off. All other SE sites including betas look fine, no zoom, no JS errors

Comment: I am using Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit) and it works perfectly for me.  (I don't know what the "m" at the end of the version number signifies.)

Comment: Interesting, I still have the issue. I'm not too sure what the m means either but I wouldn't imagine it would be an issue of chrome versions

Comment: Although my content is centered, the menu is also to low compared to pm.se for example. I am using chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 m

Comment: Do you happen to be zoomed in/out? (Ctrl + 0 to reset)

Comment: @oded 'All other SE sites including betas look fine, no zoom, no JS errors' nah no zoom or any of the other obvious things like caching, or chrome plugins (incognito is exactly the same)

Comment: @oded I had a bit more of a play, the content offset left only occurs at browser widths greater than 2145px. The missplaced header occurs for me at all browser widths

Comment: Thanks for hunting that down. I will look into this with our designers.

Comment: @oded np, it only happens on this site, so is probably in the SQA stylesheet

Comment: @oded also the header displacement occurs because #hlogo is 417px and #hmenu is 564px (total 981px) inside a 980px wide container, one of those elements needs to shrink by 1px (im guessing `#hlogo a` should be 416px. Interestingly applying that change fixes both issues

Comment: It is one of the longest site names/logos we have, which might be the reason. I was under the impression this was fixed earlier, but I guess not completely.

Comment: @Pacerier - looks fixed to me. What browser/OS are you on? Are you zoomed in/out?

Comment: @Pacerier looks fine on my machine now, and the underlying issue definitely looks fixed if you are still getting an issue it may be a different one.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that multiple answers exist in the comment section and considering that the experience seems to be rather limited to your humble self, I'd advice to close this question. Any objections?

Cheers!

Comment: Yes I do object to closing it. Just because *you* cant see the issue doesn't mean it isn't there

Comment: It's not just me, who can't see it mate.

Comment: I have the same problem :)